# SQL Server - IN clause with multiple fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, in-clause

Is it possible to include in a `IN` clause multiple fields? Something like the following:

```
select * from user
where code, userType in ( select code, userType from userType )
```

I'm using ms sql server 2008

---

I know this can be achieved with joins and exists, I just wanted to know if it could just be done with the `IN` clause.

Comment: The fact that you expect *two* columns from one table to be "IN" a second table hints at a schema design in need of further normalization.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not the way you have posted. You can only return a single field or type for `IN` to work.

From MSDN ([`IN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)):

```
test_expression [ NOT ] IN 
    ( subquery | expression [ ,...n ]
    ) 

subquery - Is a subquery that has a result set of one column. 
           This column must have the same data type as test_expression.

expression[ ,... n ] - Is a list of expressions to test for a match. 
                       All expressions must be of the same type as 
                       test_expression.
```

Instead of `IN`, you could use a `JOIN` using the two fields:

```
SELECT U.* 
FROM user U
  INNER JOIN userType UT
    ON U.code = UT.code
    AND U.userType = UT.userType
```

Comment: yeap, I suspected it wasn't possible

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/4e058e95-9d7c-4baa-a73e-3c849b4c6463                      <br>delete from test1

where not exists

( select 0 from test2

  where test1.col1 = test2.col1

    and test1.col2 = test2.col2)

Comment: @Vijay - What are you trying to say here?

Answer (score 10):

You could use a form like this:

```
select * from user u
where exists (select 1 from userType ut
              where u.code = ut.code
                and u.userType = ut.userType)
```

Comment: Well, you'll likely have to use either `EXISTS` or `JOIN` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

Only with something horrific, like

```
select * from user
where (code + userType) in ( select code + userType from userType )
```

Then you have to manage nulls and concatenating numbers rather than adding them, and casting, and a code of 12 and a usertype of 3 vs a code of 1 and a usertype of 23, and...

..which means you start heading into perhaps something like:

```
--if your SQLS supports CONCAT
select * from user
where CONCAT(code, CHAR(9), userType) in ( select CONCAT(code, CHAR(9), userType) from ... )

--if no concat
select * from user
where COALESCE(code, 'no code') + CHAR(9) + userType in ( 
  select COALESCE(code, 'no code') + CHAR(9) + userType from ... 
)
```

CONCAT will do a string concatenation of most things, and won't zip the whole output to NULL if one element is NULL. If you don't have CONCAT then you'll string concat using `+` but anything that might be null will need a COALESCE/ISNULL around it.. And in either case you'll need something like CHAR(9) (a tab) between the fields to prevent them mixing.. The thing between the fields should be southing that is not naturally present in the data..

Tis a shame SQLS doesn't support this, that Oracle does:

```
where (code, userType) in ( select code, userType from userType )
```

but it's probably not worth switching DB for; I'd use EXISTS or a JOIN to achieve a multi column filter

---

So there ya go: a solution that doesn't use joins or exists.. and a bunch of reasons why you shouldn't use it ;)

Comment: I have used this, however it only works is the fields are both strings. Also, I recommend using a character between the two fields like `|` i.e. `where (code + '|' + userType) in ( select code + '|' + userType from userType )`.  But I agree it is not a great solution.

Comment: Yet another reason why I crusade against compound primary keys. This works for me as ugly as it is. Anything else risks getting values mixed up.

Comment: @Zoey if it clobbers the performance too much, you might consider having some separate computed/indexed column that "uncompounds" the PK cols into one col, if you're desperate to avoid the other methods.. EXISTS and JOIN should be fine though, and JOIN more logical but I always did find update/delete queries easier with an IN, so I totally understand wanting to compund the PK into one

Comment: thanks @CaiusJard, that is a good idea. Luckily this is a rare thing I have to deal with. The other problem is that it's normally with our ERP system and we can't add computed fields to the DB. This will be good to keep in my pocket if it's custom legacy DBs.

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead:

```
SELECT user.* FROM user JOIN userType on user.code = userType.code AND user.userType = userType.userType
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use joins

```
SELECT * FROM user U 
INNER JOIN userType UT on U.code = UT.code 
AND U.userType = UT.userType
```

Comment: I think both queries are not equivalent, the second query can match two differents records from the table userType

Comment: Hmmm.. you are right. But it could be either one, it depends on what he wants. As he accepted the answer with joins, it must be that one. Edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something very similar but EXISTS didn't work in my situation. Here is what worked for me:

```
UPDATE tempFinalTbl
SET BillStatus = 'Non-Compliant'
WHERE ENTCustomerNo IN ( SELECT DISTINCT CustNmbr
             FROM tempDetailTbl dtl
            WHERE dtl.[Billing Status] = 'NEEDS FURTHER REVIEW'
              AND dtl.CustNmbr = ENTCustomerNo 
              AND dtl.[Service] = [Service]) 
  AND [Service] IN  ( SELECT DISTINCT [Service] 
             FROM tempDetailTbl dtl
            WHERE dtl.[Billing Status] = 'NEEDS FURTHER REVIEW'
              AND dtl.CustNmbr = ENTCustomerNo 
              AND dtl.[Service] = [Service])
```

EDIT: Now that I look, this is very close to @v1v3kn's answer

Comment: Note, this is potentially completely wrong.. Suppose you wanted to delete 23 year old John and 26 year old Jane. A where clause of `WHERE name in ('john', 'jane') AND age IN (23, 28)` is conceptually `WHERE (name = 'john' or name = 'jane') and (age = 23 or age = 26)`, which is very different to what you actually want: `WHERE (name = 'john' and age = 23) or (name = 'jane' and age = 26)`. Splitting the INs as you have done would delete anyone called john who is 23 or 26 and anyone called jane who is 23 or 26; very different from "just 23 year old john plus 26 year old jane"

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that query is quite portable,it would be safer to use something like

```
select * from user
where code in ( select code from userType ) and userType in (select userType from userType)
```

Comment: mmmm... I guess it's not the same, I'm looking for ONE record with the same code and userType...

Comment: That will not work.  You might have one record that matches your `code` and another record that matches your `userType`.

Comment: Note, this is potentially completely wrong.. Suppose you wanted to delete 23 year old John and 26 year old Jane. A where clause of `WHERE name in ('john', 'jane') AND age IN (23, 28)` is conceptually `WHERE (name = 'john' or name = 'jane') and (age = 23 or age = 26)`, which is very different to what you actually want: `WHERE (name = 'john' and age = 23) or (name = 'jane' and age = 26)`. Splitting the INs as you have done would delete anyone called john who is 23 or 26 and anyone called jane who is 23 or 26; very different from "just 23 year old john plus 26 year old jane"

Answer (score -3):

```
select * from user
where (code, userType) in ( select code, userType from userType );
```

Comment: Oracle's fine with this. but the question is about SQLS