# T-SQL equivalent to oracle sql where clause with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, row-value-expression

Let's look for example Oracle SQL, which works perfectly:

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table test (a number, b number);
SQL> insert into test values(1, 1);
SQL> insert into test values(1, 2);
SQL> insert into test values(1, 3);
SQL> insert into test values(1, 4);
SQL> insert into test values(1, 5);
SQL> insert into test values(2, 1);
SQL> insert into test values(2, 2);
SQL> insert into test values(2, 3);
SQL> insert into test values(2, 4);
SQL> insert into test values(2, 5);
SQL> insert into test values(4, 1);

SQL> select * from test;

         A          B
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
         1          4
         1          5
         2          1
         2          2
         2          3
         2          4
         2          5
         4          1
```

Query:

```
SQL> select * from test where (a, b) in (select 1, 4 from dual);

         A          B
---------- ----------
         1          4
```

Here's the sql-fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8375e/3/0

Simple question: is there any equivalent in MS SQL of above "where (a, b)" clause? I've been looking around in google, MS Docs and nothing so far...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452539/sql-server-in-clause-with-multiple-fields

Comment: How does it work in Oracle? Is it the same as `select * from test
where a = 1 and b = 4;`? What is the benefit then?

Comment: N.B: `(a, b)` is a called a "row value expression", or a tuple. This might help with googling.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474964/using-tuples-in-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 5):

While SQL Server has a [`Table Value Constructor`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) that can be used for some use-cases, SQL Server doesn't support SQL standard row value expressions and predicates derived from row value expressions for general use (yet). You will have to resort to semi-joining your subquery using an equivalent `EXISTS` clause:

This:

```
select * from test where (a, b) in (select 1, 4 from dual);
```

Is equivalent to this (see [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69171/14)):

```
select * from test where exists (
  select * from (
    select 1, 4 -- Replace with "real" subselect
  ) t(a, b)
  where test.a = t.a and test.b = t.b
)
```

Or, a bit more generically, by using a common table expression (See [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69171/6)):

```
with t(a, b) as (
  select 1, 4 -- Replace with "real" subselect
)
select * from test where exists (
  select * from t
  where test.a = t.a and test.b = t.b
)
```

Comment: Here's the [Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors) if you feel the urge to vote on it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks for the link. I will!

Answer (score 0):

How about below query, which supports in sql server; and I guess `a=1 and b=4` gives the same result in sql server equivalent to oracle query.:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    test 
where 
    a=1 and 
    b=4;
```

Comment: Is this the same as the oracle query(i don't know)? It'll give one record as the other answers but if you insert another with `a=4,b=1` you'll get two records instead of one. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24f87/5/1

Comment: Yes, my answer gives only 1 record. In oracle also output is one record(as he mentioned).

Comment: Yes, this query isn't correct. According to the SQL standard, `(a, b) = (1, 4)` is equivalent to `(a = 1) AND (b = 4)`. This accounts for the `IN` predicate and subselects just as well. Your predicate is equivalent to `(1 = a OR 1 = b) AND (4 = a OR 4 = b)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are correct; It's giving 2 records. I didn't checked with entry (4, 1) actually. So `select * from test where a=1 and b=4` will the result no?