# SQL Query with two IN statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

So let's assume I have the following setup:

I have a companies table that associates a 3 digit code with a company. (100, 200, 388, etc). Table name is companymaster, fields: companycode

A company can have many divisions, denoted by a 2 alphanumeric characters (1A, HM, A1, etc). Table name is divisionmaster, fields: companycode, divisioncode

I have a product that is then associated with a particular company division and has an 5 digit product code. Table name is productmaster, fields: companycode, divisioncode, productcode

Now say I have the following divisions:

```
100 1A, 100 1B, 100 HM, 388 1A, 388 HM
```

I want to search divisions 100 1A and 388 HM for a particular product, so one might write a query like so...

```
select
    companycode, divisioncode, productcode
from
    productmaster
where
   companycode in ('100', '388') and
   divisioncode in ('1A', 'HM')  and
   productcode = '10010'
```

If I run this query, I could potentially get products from 100 HM or 388 1A when I only want 100 1A and 388 HM.

Is there anyway to do this elegantly without a where clause like the following?

```
 where
     (companycode = '100' and divisioncode = '1A') or
     (companycode = '388' and divisioncode = 'HM')
```

If I had more companies and divisions I wanted to search, my where clause would be humongous.

Comment: not really.  You could use an exists or a join based on limits of this company and division, but both result in what you did in the where clause.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452539/sql-server-in-clause-with-multiple-fields  oracle lets you do `select * from tbl
where (Field1, Field2) in ( select Field1,Field2 from tbl2);`  you could + both columns together but then you lose the ability to index.  you could create a computed column index it and then an IN concatenating the columns together may work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems completely fine to me. Anyway you could create a table with two columns (`companycode` and `divisioncode`) and join it with your table.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (companycode VARCHAR(3), divisioncode VARCHAR(2));
INSERT INTO @T (companycode, divisioncode)
VALUES ('100', '1A')
      ,('388', 'HM');

SELECT PM.companycode
      ,PM.divisioncode
      ,PM.productcode
FROM productmaster AS PM
INNER JOIN @T AS TT
    ON  PM.companycode = TT.companycode
    AND PM.divisioncode = TT.divisioncode
WHERE PM.productcode = '10010';
```

Please, note that if performance is a concern, you may want to create a temp table (`#T`) or a real table (and drop it later) so that you can take advantage of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit naive and may result in a inefficient table scan: `CONCAT(companycode,';',divisioncode) IN ('100;1A', '388;HM')`